# NHibernate queryover how to query a field which starts with any value in a list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to write a proper nhibernate queryover query to select records from a table which has got a column value which starts with any of the value in my inmemory list?

I am trying something like below

```
select * from table where title like 'AA%' or 'BB%' or 'CC%'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I think it goes like this.

```
var disjunction = new Disjunction();

disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<YourType>(x => x.Title).IsLike('AA%');
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<YourType>(x => x.Title).IsLike('BB%');
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<YourType>(x => x.Title).IsLike('CC%');

_session.QueryOver<YourType>().Where(disjunction);
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked but only changed i did to make it work in my case is disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Asset>(x=>x.Title).IsInsensitiveLike(item,MatchMode.Start));